# How to show PickerView above anotherview

Tags: ios, uiview, uipickerview

I am a newbie in IOS, I found an example about create and show a UIPickerView in the bottom and above some views in this ... [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uu4xRQ5aj8E)...
but I have no idea to make it
Could anyone tell me how to achieve it?

- Should I add a PickerView in a Popup?
- Should I design all layout first then I drag and drop UIPickerView above (in MainStoryBoard)?
- Can I add UIPickerView programmatically in the bottom and above some view?

Any help would be appreciate

[image] =====>>>
[image]

Comment: Your question is vague to the point of absurdity. You need to state clearly what it is you want to do. Once you've stated your goal, you also need to make an attempt to solve your problem yourself. If you get stuck, post back and we can help you, but we are not your code monkeys. (If you want somebody to do your work for you then you need to pay for it.)

Comment: @DuncanC I just need an idea for this problem. I dont ask about sourcecode. I just move to IOS 3 days and I don't know how can I show a PickerView in the bottom and cover someview
Could you give me some suggestion about which knowleadge I should learn to achieve it

Comment: Ok, but doesn't the link you posted explain how to do it? What about the tutorial does not meet your needs? Does it do something different than what you want? Are you having trouble following it? Like I said, your question is extremely vague.

Comment: @DuncanC thank you. i have update my question. if you dont mind could you look at this again. i cannot find any tutorial to make it and I don't know where to start to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ActionSheetPicker from Gihub. its exactly solve your problem.

here link https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can set pickerView is inputView of uitextfield, so when your edit textfield, pickerview will be displayed

code:

```
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self
    self.textField.inputView = pickerView
```

if you want inputview of textfield is normal you can set

```
self.textField.inputView = nil
```

p/s: if you want to change inputview of uitextfield while it 's being showed, you must to call

```
self.textView.reloadInputViews()
```

Comment: with your solution, does the pickerview display as same as the video (i mean it display in the bottom and above some textview like soft keyboard) or it display in the center or below textfield

Comment: it 's like soft keyboard. Realy, what do you want? ('m Vietnamese, you too?)

Comment: Could you give me some contact information like skype or gmail? I will explain easier